# Dynamically created Tables JOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 types of tables

1. Major table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE #InitialTable
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    RP varchar(20)
) 

INSERT INTO #InitialTable 
VALUES ('R1', 'R2', 'R3')
GO
```

2. Table contains dynamically created tables information as follows

```
CREATE TABLE #DynamicTablesInfo
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    RPId int  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #InitialTable(Id),
    TableName varchar(100)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #DynamicTablesInfo 
VALUES (1, 'Table_X1'), (2, 'Table_X2'), (3, 'Table_X3')
GO
```

3. Dynamically created tables these tables can be any number of tables and the tables info is available in above table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table_X1
(   
    Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Version_Value varchar(100)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Table_X1 
VALUES ('Val_X1_1'), ('Val_X1_2'), ('Val_X1_3')
GO

CREATE TABLE #Table_X2
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Version_Value varchar(100)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Table_X2 
VALUES ('Val_X2_1'), ('Val_X2_2'), ('Val_X2_3')
GO

CREATE TABLE #Table_X3
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Version_Value varchar(100)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Table_X3 
VALUES ('Val_X3_1'), ('Val_X3_2'), ('Val_X3_3')
GO
```

Now I wanted to join `InitialTable` with dynamically created tables (`Table_X1, Table_X2, Table_X3,`....) with the help of `DynamicTablesInfo` table - how to do that?

Note: for easy update, delete, insert I created them as temporary tables but in my application all are real tables.

Comment: Dynamic query, like the dynamic tables were created. Personally I wouldn't bother creating tables dynamically; all your dyn tables have the same structure and could easily be replaced by a single table with an extra column, and that's easier to query (all youre doing by creating dynamic tables is using the table_name to store information that should be stored in a row of a column. storing info in table names is a bad idea)

Comment: So how are you creating your existing *dynamic* tables - probably you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table_X1
(   
Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
,Version_Value varchar(100)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE #Table_X2
(
Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
,Version_Value varchar(100)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE #Table_X3
(
Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
,Version_Value varchar(100)
)
GO
```

Do this one time:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_X
(   
Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
,Version_Value varchar(100)
,X_number INT
)
GO
```

Then instead of doing this:

```
INSERT INTO #Table_X1 VALUES ('Val_X1_1'),('Val_X1_2'),('Val_X1_3')
INSERT INTO #Table_X2 VALUES ('Val_X2_1'),('Val_X2_2'),('Val_X2_3')
INSERT INTO #Table_X3 VALUES ('Val_X3_1'),('Val_X3_2'),('Val_X3_3')
```

Do this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_X VALUES ('Val_X1_1',1),('Val_X1_2',1),('Val_X1_3',1)
INSERT INTO Table_X VALUES ('Val_X2_1',2),('Val_X2_2',2),('Val_X2_3',2)
INSERT INTO Table_X VALUES ('Val_X3_1',3),('Val_X3_2',3),('Val_X3_3',3)
```

Much easier to query without dynamics:

```
--no
SELECT * FROM Table_X1

--yes
SELECY * FROM Table_X WHERE X_Number = 1
```

---

You've indicated you're stuck with it how it is, so you'll need to create and run your queries dynamically too. This is c#/vb flavored pseudocode:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM sometable"

for int x = 1 to 3
  sql = sql + " table_x{x} on sometable.id = table_x{x}.id"
```

Or perhaps build a Union:

```
string sql = "WITH allx AS (SELECT * FROM table_x1"

for int x = 2 to 10
  sql = sql + " UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_x{x}"

sql = sql + ") select * from sometable inner join allx on..."
```

But I echo larnu's sentiments in the comments.. if you truly cannot change the tables that are created, consider creating a VIEW in a similar way to the UNION code above, that will sit alongside X number of tables and will provide a way to query without dynamic:

```
CREATE VIEW AllX AS(
  SELECT x.*, 1 as Which FROM TABLE_X1 x
  UNION ALL SELECT x.*, 2 as Which FROM TABLE_X2 x
  UNION ALL SELECT x.*, 3 as Which FROM TABLE_X3 x
  ...
```

Use the same technique that creates 10 tables to string together a CREATE VIEW statement that views over the 10 tables, then you can query the view without Dynamic sql generation

Comment: Thank you @Caius Jard your answer is perfect when I am trying to create from scratch. But in our case the tables and logic is already created as i mentioned in the question. We didn't have any control on table creation. If the tables are as it is in above question can you suggest me the answer.

Comment: The code you have will create table dynamically so it should also create the joins dynamically. Perhaps you could instead dynamically create a Union and join just once

Comment: Forcing yourself down the dynamic SQL approach is a trap, if I am honest @KrishnaReddy . Redesign the database now, and you don't have this problem. You, with respect, are clearly not familiar with dynamic SQL and thus making so you have to is going to be both a nightmare to maintain and likely a huge security risk.

Comment: Agree with Larnu  and added another suggestion to help towards that recommendation if you really have someone with a gun to your head saying "the Table_x cannot ever change" (altering their opinion should be your first attempt at solving the problem)